# How can you scroll a ListBox to the bottom

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listbox, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.8

How can you scroll a List Box to the bottom in C#?
The items in the ListBox don't have names, which may make it more difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this..

```
 listbox.ScrollIntoView(listbox.Items[listbox.Items.Count - 1]);
```

Comment: It's a ListBox, not a scroll viewer.

Comment: i am really sorry for the mistake i have done ..hopw it will solve your problem..

Comment: it seems to scroll almost to the end of the ListBox but seems to stop halfway through the last item.

Answer (score 1):

In C#:

```
yourListBox.SelectedIndex = yourListBox.ItemsSource.Count();
```

If for some reason you do not have `Count`, try this:

```
public static int Count<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
  if (source == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
  ICollection collection = source as ICollection;
  if (collection != null)
    return collection.Count;
  int num = 0;
  foreach (TSource item in source)
      checked { ++num; }
  return num;
}
```

Comment: This brings up an error, saying there is no definition for .Count andthere is no extension method for .Count

Comment: @Newbie Add `using System.Linq;` to the top of your file.

Comment: I am already using System.Linq; as its a default statement for windows phone projects

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance Can't he use `yourListBox.Items.Count` directly?

Comment: @anderZubi Not if it's not an ICollection, no.